# Trouble with using substring to select data frame rows

Tags: python, pandas

### Python 2.7

```
In [3]:import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=['abc','abc','abc','xyz','xyz'],
                       B='abcdef','abcdefghi','notthisone','uvwxyz','orthisone']))
In [4]: df
Out[4]:
    A   B
0   abc abcdef
1   abc abcdefghi
2   abc notthisone
3   xyz uvwxyz
4   xyz orthisone

In [12]:  df[df.B.str.contains(df.A) == True] 
# just keep the B that contain A string

TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

---

I am trying for this:

```
    A   B
0   abc abcdef
1   abc abcdefghi
3   xyz uvwxyz
```

I have tried variations of the str.contains statement, but no go.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like `str.contains` supports multiple patterns, so you may just have to apply over the rows:

```
substr_matches = df.apply(lambda row: row['B'].find(row['A']) > -1, axis=1)

df.loc[substr_matches]
Out[11]: 
     A          B
0  abc     abcdef
1  abc  abcdefghi
3  xyz     uvwxyz
```

Answer (score 2):

Apply a lambda function on the rows and test if A is in B.

```
>>> df[df.apply(lambda x: x.A in x.B, axis=1)]
     A          B
0  abc     abcdef
1  abc  abcdefghi
3  xyz     uvwxyz
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html#pandas.Series.unique) on column 'A' and then join with `|` to create a pattern for matching using [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas.Series.str.contains):

```
In [15]:
df[df['B'].str.contains('|'.join(df['A'].unique()))]

Out[15]:
     A          B
0  abc     abcdef
1  abc  abcdefghi
3  xyz     uvwxyz
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this ?

```
In [8]: df[df.apply(lambda v: v['A'] in v['B'], axis=1)]
Out[8]: 
     A          B
0  abc     abcdef
1  abc  abcdefghi
3  xyz     uvwxyz
```